Get companies from ACC Admin API with 3-legged authentication?
I try to get companies associated with account by calling the ACC Admin API endpoint: https://developer.api.autodesk.com/hq/v1/regions/eu/accounts/:account_id/companies
Problem is the response I get is {code: 1003, message: "Only support 2 legged access token."}.
Is this true? As I read in the documentation and it should be able to use both 2 and 3-legged authorization.
I try to get companies associated with account by calling the ACC Admin API endpoint: https://developer.api.autodesk.com/hq/v1/regions/eu/accounts/:account_id/companies
I expect to be able to use 3-legged authentication.

Almost all the Admin API seems to be app only, i.e. needs 2-legged access token:
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/reference/http/companies-GET/

You'll see user context optional where you can use 3-legged access token as well.
